# I am having trouble with a Python list display using "in range"

Tags: python, list

My first question here, so if I don't do something correctly, please tell me so I can correct it and/or do it correctly next time.

I am trying to allow a user to input ten numbers, then spit them back out in the reverse order they gave them.  I can't get the ranges right, though, because it keeps either asking me for just 9 numbers, or it doesn't assign anything to the last variable in my list.

I am using Python 3.x.

Here is my code:

```
#Creating my list
myNumbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

#Creating a for loop for inputs
for A in range (1,10):
    myNumbers[A]=input("Enter a number: ")


#Creating a for loop for outputs
for B in range (10,1,-1):
    print(myNumbers[B])
```

It's only allowing me to input 9 numbers, and then my output is the number 11, then my reverse input.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Besides nneonneo's answer, using the interpreter to test things like this is always a good idea.  If you start up the python interpreter you can just type `range(10)` and your other variations for easy answers.

Comment: Everyone is awesome for helping me.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range` always omits the last value, and starts from 0 by default (remember that lists are 0-indexed in Python, so a 10-element list has indices 0 through 9).

```
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also, instead of using `range(10,1,-1)`, I would recommend just using `reversed`:

```
for i in reversed(range(10)): # iterates from 9 down to 0
```

or, since you are just printing out the items in the list, just iterate over the reversed list items directly:

```
for item in reversed(myNumbers):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `range` returns an iterable object, not a list, so your first example won't work the same way. You can use `list(range(10))` to see the values, instead. The rest of this answer is very good though!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's only letting you enter 9 numbers, is that the first element in a list has index of `0`, so you should be assigning to `A[0]...A[9]`

If you start with an empty list, you can `append` to it as many times as you wish, so you don't need to know the size in advance.

```
my_numbers = []

for i in range(10):
    my_numbers.append(input("Enter a number: "))

for item in reversed(my_numbers):
    print(item)
```

Loop variables in Python don't have to be numbers, you can iterate over anything that returns a sequence of objects.

There is a shorthand way of creating a list like this called a list comprehension. Then your program becomes just 3 lines

```
my_numbers = [input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(10)]

for item in reversed(my_numbers):
    print(item)
```

Comment: ``print '\n'.join(item for item in reversed([input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(10)]))`` :)

Comment: ``print '\n'.join(reversed([input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(10)]))``  !!

Comment: @eyquem, if you want to golf it, you should use `for i in '.'*10`. Also use `[...][::-1]` to reverse the list comprehension :)

Comment: No, not code golf. It was because you wrote _"Then your program becomes just 3 lines"_ , I tried to reduce the number of lines. Code golf is only game of number of characters, whereas I'm interested to diminish the number of lines and instructions in order to diminish the time and effort the interpreter takes, while however  keping clarity for reading. In this spirit, though tricky to write ``for i in 10*'.'``, I don't retain this writing because it isn't an instantly understandable of what is wanted - BTW I added an update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using range (0,10) instead of range (1,10)

range (1,10) is similar to `for (i=1;i<10;i++)` which runs only 9 times(does not run for i=10)
also, the array index starts from 0 and not 1

Answer (score 0):

```
print( '\n'.join(reversed([input("Enter a number: ") for i in range(10)])) )
```

or

```
li = []
for i in xrange(4):
    li.insert(0,input("Enter a number: ")
print( '\n'.join(li) )
```

This solution doesn't create a new (reversed) list object. We directly construct the desired list.
It can be shortened to

```
li = []
any(li.insert(0,input("Enter a number: ")) for i in xrange(4))
print( '\n'.join(li) )
```

Comment: `print` is a function in Python3